# Antd DatePicker: Input in extra footer can't change, select or focus

Tags: reactjs, antd, datetimepicker

I am working with antd `Datepicker` and I want custom `Datepicker` component look like this.

[image]

Now, I use prop `renderExtraFooter` to add custom footer. My input time in footer is other lib (react-datepicker). My problem is here. I can't change, select, focus any input render in extra footer. I want my input time can use (select, change, focus, ...) but I don't know how to do this.

Here is my trying code: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-custom-antd-12hgbd

I try `.blur()` antd `Datepicker` input but still not work.

Any can help me or tell me a lib to custom DatePicker look like picture. Thank for your help.

Comment: You can try [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-custom-antd-forked-smu3bg?file=/src/App.js) one too on your CodeSanbox code.

Comment: Although, I made it work without `e.stopPropagation()` but as suggested in the answer, this works, that too better without my hack

Comment: Instead of a separate button, you can use ok button of the Ant design's date picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution is kind of an hack & you will need to handle *open* & *closing* of the panel via a state variable.

```
<DatePicker
  showToday={false}
  open={true}
  renderExtraFooter={() => (
    <div onMouseDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
     <input />
    </div>
  )}
/>
```

[image: Edit Extra Footer - Input Focus]

If you remove the `open={true}` prop, the input will focus but the picker will close immediately. You need to control the visibility of the panel with the `open` property.